# Limiting size of GeoServer log file?

Tags: geoserver, log

I have some configuration or something like that where i can do to limit the size of log geoserver (like 1 Gb), or maybe delete entire log like 1 time of week?

Because my logs never stop to increase, like 5 GB, 7GB etc

Comment: There is something about how to configure logging in document http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/logging.html. Further advice must probably be searched from log4j manuals or from StackOverflow with tag "log4j". RollingFileAppender is propably what you need and one answer about that is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056481/log4j-configure-rollingfileappender-for-backup-log-files-as-dailyrollingfileap.

Answer (score 7):

The size of the geoserver.log file is already limited to 10MB, it's then going to roll it and keep a few copies (3 or 4).

If you are deploying on Tomcat, the size of catalina.out is out of GeoServer control, and the file is not rolled. Your best option is to disable "logging to stdout" in the GeoServer log configuration:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html

Comment: updated link to settings docs: http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this by adding this line:

```
log4j.appender.geoserverlogfile.MaxFileSize=10000KB
```

to a file

```
[GeoServer data dir]\logs\[Your logging profile].properties
```

Setting value to "10MB" didn't work.